# How to set constraints to set height of UIView same as flexible height of adjacent view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, constraints, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have a view in **storyboard** with UIView that contains an image:

[image]

When I compile the table, I get:

[image]

But, in another case in storyboard without image:

[image]

I get result:

[image]

My **UITableView** is working with **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**

The question is:

**How to set constrains of my `UIImageView` to determine its height same as max height of adjacent view?**

Answer (score -1):

Add two constraints to the UIImageView to constrain it to the Top and Bottom of the UIView